# Segmentation fault as soon the binary launch

Tags: c, linux, debugging

How to debug a segmentation fault caused by launching the binary on Linux?
No source code is available for the binary.

How to know the system calls made by the binary which caused the seg fault. Is there any debugging utility that might help?

Comment: You can try running the executable with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck) and see if it reports any obvious issues

Comment: what's the actual program that you are running?

Comment: I disagree with the reasosn to close this.

Answer (score 7):

Does `strace your-program` help you? It will print a list of all system calls called by your program.

## Sample Output

```
% strace true
```

.

```
    2       2 [main] true (2064) **********************************************
   83      85 [main] true (2064) Program name: C:\cygwin\bin\true.exe (windows pid 2064)
   44     129 [main] true (2064) OS version:   Windows NT-6.1
   36     165 [main] true (2064) **********************************************
  145     310 [main] true (2064) sigprocmask: 0 = sigprocmask (0, 0x6123D468, 0x610FBA10)
  183     493 [main] true 2064 open_shared: name shared.5, n 5, shared 0x60FF0000 (wanted 0x60FF0000), h 0x70, *m 6
   27     520 [main] true 2064 heap_init: heap base 0x20000000, heap top 0x20000000, heap size 0x18000000 (402653184)
   30     550 [main] true 2064 open_shared: name foo, n 1, shared 0x60FE0000 (wanted 0x60FE0000), h 0x68, *m 6
   18     568 [main] true 2064 user_info::create: opening user shared for 'foo' at 0x60FE0000
   17     585 [main] true 2064 user_info::create: user shared version 6467403B
   36     621 [main] true 2064 fhandler_pipe::create: name \\.\dir\cygwin-c5e39b7a9d22bafb-2064-sigwait, size 164, mode PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE
   51     672 [main] true 2064 fhandler_pipe::create: pipe read handle 0x84
   16     688 [main] true 2064 fhandler_pipe::create: CreateFile: name \\.\dir\cygwin-c5e39b7a9d22bafb-2064-sigwait
   35     723 [main] true 2064 fhandler_pipe::create: pipe write handle 0x88
   23     746 [main] true 2064 dll_crt0_0: finished dll_crt0_0 initialization
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what's been suggested you can also do the following:

Run `ulimit -c unlimited` to enable core dumping, then run your app.

At the point of segfaulting it should do a core dump.

Then you can run `gdb your_app core` and inside gdb run `backtrace`. Maybe it's been compiled with debugging symbols so you actually get quite a bit of information out.